# Is my approach secure for implementing a one-time password in web service security

Tags: web-services, security

I have two systems (A & B) that i need to integrate with each other using web services, so i am thinking of implementing the following security mechanism:-

1. system B will send a request containing a username and password to system A asking for the one time 64-char password.
2. System A  will send a onetime password containing 64 characters to system B.
3. System B will call system A web services using the 64 characters password.
4. System A will check if the 64 -char password is valid.
5. system A will respond to system B request.
6. system A will removed the 64 password from the valid password (so incase system B or another system calls system A web services using the previously generated 64-char password the call will fail)
7. system A will generate a new 64-char password and send it to system B when needed.
8. system B calls system A web service using the newly 64-password.

So my question will this approach be secure baring in mind that i will implement the communication between the two system to be under https.
Best Regards

Comment: Why not encrypt the requests where system A encrypts data with the public key from system B, system B then decrypts it using its private key, and vice versa. So no need to keep using different passwords, also will allow verification that way as well if you want to do that too. Public key cryptography would be the way I would go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the web services offered by system A are used to retrieve images and documents so it will be inefficient to encrypt all the documents and images that should be returned . instead of that i will have a token or one time password that i will apply to the href attribute of the links that i am going to build on run-time, so in this way i will only deliver the documents that the user need to open in the network.

Answer (score 1):

There are many security considerations that need to be taken into account. So lets start:

- Are both systems publicly accessible ?
- Are both systems WS's publicly accessible?
- Do you want to implements encrypton ? In transport or Access Control ?

From what I can tell I presume Your systems WS's are not publicly accessible and let's say proxies incorporate some sort of certificate authentication just as an extra layer of control, and some form of Access control Lists to limit IP range of client systems.

Second thing is that You probably want to do some kind of access controll rather than encryption i.e. user **A** can view doc **aa** and **ab** and your system A knows those rules but system B does not but he holds the actual data.

Analyzing your protocol If system A authenticates against system B and gets valid OTP, there are some things to consider

- what will be validity period of such otp ?
- how will you provide uniquness ?
- will they be context dependent ?

All this is needed because you would not want, some more than avarage user to substitute data identifiers and with valid OPT access something that he/she shouldn't. Security is a slippery subject I would recomend Security Engineering by Ross Anderson and Computer Security by Dieter Gollman as starters :).

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, system A is a desktop application that exposes web services which is accessible for public but to call these web services any system should include both the master login username and password, and same thing applies to system B which is a web based application. The on-time-password or token that will be send from system A to B will be unique as we will apply a format such as currentdate+currentime+username+randome generated number. regarding the authorization rules for viewing the docuemnts they are already implemented on system A. So is my approach valid?

Comment: One thing that I missed is point 7 will this password be sent as a reply to a successfull method call ? or Will system B have to reauthenticate with username/password ? What with the validity period ? Anad what about transport layer security will you use ssl ? Remeber that passing auth data in req params will be logged by most of proxies.